# Client-side Development Platforms based on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, runtime, rich-internet-application

I'd like to set this up as a post where all known JavaScript client development platforms could be listed by company/organization/ecosystem.
* anything that is HTML/JavaScript-based.

**Microsoft**
[Windows Gadgets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370867%28VS.85%29.aspx)*
[HTA - HTML Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471%28VS.85%29.aspx)*

**Adobe**
[Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tools/sdk/)* Can be done with only HTML/JS but can also can use Flex/Flash
[Adobe Director](http://www.adobe.com/products/director/)
[Adobe PDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html)

**Yahoo**
[Konfabulator](http://widgets.yahoo.com/tools/)

**Google**
[Google Desktop Gadgets](http://desktop.google.com/plugins/) - SDK link on the left

**Mozilla/Firefox**
[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748)
[XUL Runner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner)

**Appcelerator**
Titanium

What did I miss? Should I also list JScript.NET, managed JScript, [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)?

note: I've set this up as a community wiki.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the platform. But maybe someone could comment on development on the Palm Pre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also Titanium.

http://www.appcelerator.com/

You can use JavaScript, Python, or Ruby for desktop apps. I believe that mobile apps are JavaScript (no Python or Ruby).

Answer (score 1):

In this context the Universal Widget API might be interesting - it's designed to be a framework to write widgets for different platforms (desktop or online):

http://dev.netvibes.com/

Widgets written with the UWA work on iGoogle, Windows Vista, Apple Dashboard, Live.com, iPhone, and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mobile 6.5 (MS Smart Phone OS) will support HTML/JavaScript Widgets similar to Vista/Windows 7 Widgets:

[Windows Mobile Developer](http://developer.windowsmobile.com/)

Looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Qt with QtScript.

Answer (score 0):

How about Ext Js!

Comment: Can you do full on client dev with this? I thought it was just a JavaScript library?

Comment: It's a full client-side JavaScript framework actually. Check it out http://extjs.com/ .

Comment: Ext JS is a JavaScript library and Ext GWT is a Java library aimed at Google's GWT. To my knowledge, Ext JS depends on being hosted in a browser or a browser-like environment. If it can be used in some other way, please point to something more illuminative than the project's homepage.

Comment: Yep. Ext JS is a Cross-Browser Rich Internet Application Framework (JS Library) Perhaps I misunderstood the question. 

If you're building a "Web" based client UI (ajax, windows look and feel) it's pretty awesome in my experience. ... You could always host the site locally in IIS on the client =).